# Grammar - correct adjective ending in dative case

Tags: grammatical-case

Sentence:

> Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von deren eigenwillige**n** und leicht chaotische**n** Erscheinen.

I know the adjectives end in 'n' when using the demonstrative pronoun, i.e. '**vom** eigenwillige**n** Erscheinen', or when using possessive pronoun, i.e. 'von **meinem** eigenwillige**n** Erscheinen, whereas it's 'm' in the indefinite case, '**von** eigenwillige**m** Erscheinen'. Given that the sentence uses possessive 'deren', it should thus be 'n', but it *sounds odd* to me. So the alternative would be

> Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von deren eigenwillige**m** und leicht chaotische**m** Erscheinen.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deren` ist hier ein vorangestelltes Genitivattribut, und als solches verlangt es starke Beugung (d. h. die Beugung, die ohne Artikel verwendet wird). Die Übertragung auf den eingangs zitierten Satz ist einfach:

> Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von deren eigenwillige**m** und leicht chaotische**m** Erscheinen.

Drei Referenzen hierzu:

1) Duden – die Grammatik, 7. Auflage Mannheim 2006), Abschnitt 2.3.1:

> Nach den Wortformen *dessen* und *deren* werden die folgenden Adjektive immer stark flektiert.

Beispiele:

> für ... deren *jüngere* Geschwister
>   an dessen *siebentem* Jahrestag
>   an deren *äußerster* Spitze

2) [Dr. Bopp von Canoo.net:](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2016/01/26/dessen-deren-und-deren-nachfolgende-nachbarn/)

> dessen [hat] keinen Einfluss auf das ihm folgende Adjektiv ... Damit ist gemeint, dass das Adjektiv gleich gebeugt wird, wie wenn gar kein Artikelwort vor ihm steht (starke Beugung ...)

Beispiele:

> verärgert über das Ministerium und dessen zurückhaltendes Engagement
>
> mir ihrer Mutter und deren neue**m** Freund
>
> wegen dessen unerlaubt**er** Online-Bestellung

3) Duden – Die deutsche Rechtschreibung, 25. Auflage Mannheim 2009, zitiert nach [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=852297&lp=ende) (von dieser Stelle nur Beispiele, keine Regelerklärung):

> mit deren nettem Mann; von deren bester Art; seit deren erstem Hiersein

Hier noch ein Rat von Dr. Bopp an der oben zitierten Stelle:

> Wenn Sie einmal unsicher sind, wie es nach dessen oder deren weitergehen soll, lassen Sie dessen oder deren einfach weg, achten Sie sich [sic!] nicht allzu sehr auf den Sinn des verbleibenden Satzes(!) und sehen Sie, wie das Adjektiv dann gebeugt würde.

Comment: Der Fall aus der Frage ist *mit deren nette**m** Mann*.

Answer (score 2):

I think *Erscheinen* has to be read as plural here, and this is the reason why it's eigenwillig**en**.

After *deren* the strong declension should apply: If we look at the nominative it's *deren eigenwilliges Erscheinen*, not *deren eigenwillige Erscheinen* (compare: *das eigenwillige Erscheinen*, here **das** calls for weak declension, but *deren* doesn't).

So I think if it was singular, it had to be *eigenwilligem*, at least until someone comes up with a rule that the cases have to be treated differently.

Comment: it's definitely singular, 'das Erscheinen der Klänge'... You basically can't put Erscheinen in plural, you'd use a different word, e.g. 'die Erscheinungen der Klänge'

Comment: There is no "das", actually there is no article at all, so how can you be sure it's singular? I agree that usually you don't put infinitives into plural, but I think it's the only way to read the sentence as grammatically correct. The other explanation is that the writer made a mistake.

Comment: "that writer" is myself, so I'm sure I intend it to be singular ;)

Comment: @0__ Then RHa gave the answer in the second part: if it is singular, it has to be *eigenwilligem*.

Comment: It's singular, and it simply has to be **dem** instead of **deren**. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von *deren* eigenwilligen und leicht chaotischen Erscheinen.

Let's use *dem* instead, add another *der Klänge* and it gets much clearer:

> Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von *dem* eigenwilligen und leicht chaotischen Erscheinen *der Klänge*.

It should be pretty clear **die Klänge** isn't the object in neither the first nor the second clause. In the first, the object is **die Reinheit der Klänge**, in the second it's **das Erscheinen der Klänge**, *die Klänge* is just a genitive attribute. Both objects are singular.

The original author got confused about his own omission of *der Klänge* in the second clause and falsely used **deren** instead of the correct **dem**.

Comment: "deren" kann als Verweis sowohl auf "Klänge" als auch auf "Reinheit" verwendet werden, auch wenn "Reinheit" und nicht "Klänge" der Kopf der vorausgegangenen Nominalphrase ist. Da das Pronomen in beiden Fällen identisch ist, muss das Bezugswort aus dem Kontext ermittelt werden (und der ist hier klar). Dein erster Satz ist korrekt und idiomatisch, der zweite (mit "dem ... Klänge") grammatikalisch korrekt, aber nicht idiomatisch. Ich verstehe also nicht, was der Autor durcheinandergebracht haben soll.

Comment: Der erste Satz ist nicht korrekt, weil nicht die Klänge weiter charakterisiert werden, sondern das Erscheinen. Und das Erscheinen ist Singular, auch wenn es sich um mehrere Klänge handelt. Alternativ könnte man schreiben: *Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und von deren jeweilige**m** eigenwilligen und leicht chaotischen Erscheinen.* oder einfacher *Er war fasziniert von der Reinheit der Klänge und (von) ihre**m** eigenwilligen und leicht chaotischen Erscheinen.*

Comment: Der vereinfachte Satz "Die Klänge und deren Erscheinen faszinierten ihn." wäre demnach auch schon falsch, oder? Der Rückbezug mit "deren/dessen" auf das vorangegangene Nomen ist jedoch eindeutig korrekt.

Comment: Nein, denn in diesem vereinfachen Satz steht kein **von**. Du musst drei Fälle auseinanderhalten *Genitiv*, *von+Dativ*, *von+Genitiv*. Alle drei bedeuten etwas Unterschiedliches. Der Originalsatz vermischt zwei Fälle und ist daher falsch.

Comment: Kann diese Unterteilung in drei Fälle nicht nachvollziehen. Die Frage erscheint mir nicht sehr kompliziert, siehe auch meine Antwort.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: the -m ending (dativ strong inflection for maskulin/neutrum) for adjectives occurs *only* when the adjectives are (1) not preceded by an article; and (2) the preceding word does not indicate case, gender, or number.

However, *deren*, the preceding word, does indicate case, gender, and number.

So you do not use the -m ending.

I suspect it sounds weird to you because *deren* comes later in our studies than the other possessive pronouns. If you had a sentence with *meinem* instead, you wouldn't bat an eye at using -n for the following adjectives.

Comment: Die Regel (2) war mir zwar nicht bekannt, aber mir scheint, dass "deren" weder Fall noch Geschlecht oder Zahl der nachfolgenden Nominalphrase angibt: Es bliebe gleich, wenn wir von "Erscheinungsform" oder "Erscheinungsformen" statt "Erscheinen" sprächen. Das Pronomen bezieht sich vielmehr auf "Klänge". Die Regel wäre hier also eher nicht anwendbar, oder?

Comment: @EndreBoth I think this is correct, and the answer is wrong.